# JMSSerializerBundle with FOSRESTbundle serializes 'GET' with 'entities' tag

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializationBundle. When I get a Collection I get something like this:

```
{ "entities": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "mainDiagnosticName": "diagnostic",
        "mainDiagnosticCode": "code",
        "startDate": "2011-01-04T21:30:40+0000",
        "endDate": null,
        "patient": null
     }]
 }
```

I don't want the entities stuff. I just want:

```
 [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "mainDiagnosticName": "diagnostic",
        "mainDiagnosticCode": "code",
        "startDate": "2011-01-04T21:30:40+0000",
        "endDate": null,
        "patient": null
     }]
```

How this can be done?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found out:

This is because I was using the annotation *FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View*, I've changed by returning my own view:

```
return $this->view($entities,Codes::HTTP_OK);
```

With an array, as hd.deman said.

And it works the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `array` instance `ArrayCollection` to `FosVeiw`.

convert your results to array like this:

```
$collection->toArray()
```

Comment: Thanks! You guide me through the solution!